# how to get image from json api flutter (Mobile)

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for a way to get images from json.

json from api -->

```
[
  {
 
    "atdScanFileNameIn": "ATD_6410063_20231030_0914_CEF6_638342540745330792.png",
    "atdScanFileOldNameIn": "image470.png",
    "atdScanMimeTypeIn": "application/octet-stream",
    "atdScanPathFileIn": "image/Employee/100000/Attendance/202310",
  
  }
]
```

I use :

```
Image(
width: 100,
image: NetworkImage("https://url.com/${e.atdScanPathFileIn}/${e.atdScanFileNameIn}"))
```

But can't call the picture.
I want to show pictures from json api.

Comment: You need to add some more information, what is your input you are getting, what is your expected output ? And what method you are going to use and what you have tried so far..

Comment: @SARANSURYA I have specified more.

Comment: print out the full URL and paste to browser, is the URL  valid?

Comment: @JohnJoe i am try out edit URL, It worked. :)

Comment: "_But can't call the picture._“ What error you get?

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://dev-ismart.interexpress.co.th/ISMART/HR_Employee/6410063/Attendance/202310/ATD_6410063_20231030_0914_CEF6_638342540745330792.png

Comment: the error told you everything, your url is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble displaying the image from the JSON API using the `NetworkImage` widget, there are several things you should verify:

1. **Correct URL**:
   Ensure that the constructed URL is correct. You can print it out to the console and then try to access it in a web browser:

   ```dart
   print("https://url.com/${e.atdScanPathFileIn}/${e.atdScanFileNameIn}");
   ```

   If you can access the image directly from the browser, then the URL is correct.
2. **Error Handling**:
   Wrap your `Image` widget inside a `Builder` widget and handle errors using the `errorBuilder` attribute. This can provide insights if the image fails to load:

   ```dart
   Image.network(
     "https://url.com/${e.atdScanPathFileIn}/${e.atdScanFileNameIn}",
     errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
       print('Error Handler: $exception');
       return Text('');  // return any widget to display in case of error
     },
   )
   ```

If after trying the above suggestions you still face issues, provide any error messages or further details, and I'll be happy to assist further.